# Can somehow show progress on file upload without using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload, server-side

Let's say that I upload a file using a basic multipart post. The server then receives the request and starts to execute the server side code. **Can I somehow in that state start to output the response and after some data is sent start to receive the file?** Finally when the file is uploaded I output the rest of the response.

If this is possible I can display file upload progress without using ajax?

I guess this might depend on what I run server side. But let's assume that I have full network control.

Comment: Which server-side platform are you on?  The answer varies between .Net, PHP, Java, etc.

Comment: Actually it's CGI application in C++. If you have a PHP version you can post it and I can port the solution. I just want to get a general Idea how this can be done

Answer (score -1):

Why not just display a spinning icon?
[Google Image Search](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&safe=active&gbv=2&tbs=isch:1,isz:i&sa=1&q=wait&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

Comment: Sure I can do that but I want to show the actual progress. to clarify I want to. 1. send request. 2. Output data (html and javascript). 3. receive part of file. 4. Output data. 5. receive part of file 6. Output data. 7. receive the last part of file 6. Output the rest of the html.

Answer (score -1):

It's not AJAX-free but it seems to do everything else you want.  At the very least you might be able to reverse engineer a solution more to your liking...

http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/