# Show file upload progress without JavaScript upload

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I have a regular HTML form which POSTs several large images to a website.

Is it possible to use JavaScript to monitor how quick the upload process is?  I don't want to upload the files using `XMLHttpRequest` or jQuery.

The basic HTML is a form, some files, a button, and a progress bar.

```
<form id="fileform" action="/add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="true;">
    <input id="photoFile1" name="userfile1" type="file" accept="image/jpeg" />
    <input id="photoFile2" name="userfile2" type="file" accept="image/jpeg" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Upload"/>
    <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
</form>
```

Once the button is clicked, I can calculate the file size:

`var fileSize = document.getElementById("photoFile1").files[0].size + document.getElementById("photoFile2").files[0].size`

How can I monitor how many bytes have been sent by the browser, so that I can update the `progress` bar?

- I've looked at [jQuery Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) but that requires me to POST using JavaScript. Which would mean changing the architecture of my site.
- There is a similar question at " [Can somehow show progress on file upload without using AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920574/can-somehow-show-progress-on-file-upload-without-using-ajax) "- but it is 8 years old and unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Browsers do not provide any API that would make this possible.